# groupby get the average length name

Tags: mysql, group-by, string-length

I'm using the group by function to get some products from my little shop like:

```
select name, ProductID from blog group by ProductID

+----------------------------------------------------------+
| name                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| AAA                                                      |
| BBBB                                                     |
| CCCC                                                     |
| DDDDDDDD                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to get the average length name in the groupby function?

EDIT (from OP, placed in answer):

```
myysql> select length(name) as len, name from product where article=40 order by len asc;
+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| len  | name                                                     |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|    3 | aaa                                                      |
|    6 | BBBBBB                                                   |
|    6 | CCCCCC                                                   |
|    8 | dddddddd                                                 |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

by this example I need to get one value like BBBBBB or CCCCCC (AVG?)

Comment: Length of the string in mysql is `CHAR_LENGTH`, so in your case would be `MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(name))/COUNT(DISTINCT(name))` but that is highly inefficient index-wise. You should have a separate column with length pre-calculated in it if that is what you need. If not, you should clarify what you need better.

Comment: In your example, what is the answer? 1 value at 4.75 ((3+4+4+8)/4)? Or for each row the average length of the name because there is more than 1 name per ProductID?

Comment: by this example i need BBBB or CCCC not the smallest length and not the longest length

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't get the average length name, because there is no such thing.  The average length would be (8 + 3 + 6 + 6) / 4 = 5.75.  It doesn't exist.  I think you want the median, which is the size such that 50% are bigger and 50% are smaller.

Here is one way to get the median (assuming that names don't contain commas and that the concatenation doesn't exceed certain limits):

```
select ProductID,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(name order by length(name) separator '||'
                                                   ), '||', 1 + count(*)/2
                                      ), '||', -1) as MedianLengthName
from blog
group by ProductID;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon for this solution, is that possible to chance the char from "," to "||" ? thanks

Comment: substring_index(group_concat(name order by length(Name) SEPARATOR '||'), '||', count(*)/2) as MedianLengthName - this is not working :(

Comment: Doesn't this just list half of the names - those with the smallest lengths?  For instance, if the GROUP_CONCAT returns `1,22,333,4444,55555`, wouldn't it return '1,22' but the median is 333?

Comment: right, i have tested it :/ any other solutions? the separator should be ||.. this is also not working ./

Comment: @AgRizzo . .  . I think I fixed both those problems. One was just an "off-by-one" error.  The second was stupider . . . leaving out the second `substring_index()` to get the last value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT AVG(CHAR_LENGTH(name)) AS avg FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an the mean average (which implies you would have to accept the integer above and below that decimal value), you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT AVG(CHAR_LENGTH(name)) AS average
  FROM product) AS calculated
JOIN product
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(name) BETWEEN FLOOR(average) AND CEILING(average);
```